# Drawing in the center of an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, discord.py

```py
def centerdraw(img, msg, color, font):
    W, H = img.size
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    w, h = draw.textsize(msg, font=font)
    draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), msg, color=color, font=font)
```

so I have this which draws the message I sent in the centre of the image

```py
    img = Image.open('name1.png')
    if len(ctx.author.name) > 9:
        msg = ctx.author.name[:9]
    if len(ctx.author.name) <= 9:
        msg = ctx.author.name
    color = (0, 0, 0)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('bubblegum.ttf', 27)
    centerdraw(img=img, msg=msg, color=color, font=font)
    img.save('newname1.png')
```

I have this code which draws the ctx.author.name onto the image (ctx is defined). But it isnt doing anything. It doesnt draw what it is supposed to draw. When I first tried it, it worked but afterwards it stopped working. Any help? Btw the `ctx.author.name` is related to discord.py, it basically returns a `str` object.

[image: this is the image]
this is the image (its on the left) Its totally white

Comment: Have you validated that the img size is larger than the textsize? have you put explicit values into `your draw.text` to get it to work? What changed? If it was working now isn't try to identify the elements that have changed.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn Yes I tried the text with different sizes I tried 10, 27, 30 50, and 100 but it changed nothing also none of the elements changed

Comment: create minimal working code with example data so we could simply copy and run it. Problem can be only font which we don't have. OR maybe your problem makes font. Did you try with standard fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found an answer. I had to convert the image to RGB mode [like this](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/513) and then do whatever I wanna do